# Evenly space out horz links and bullets between links across nav bar

Tags: html, css

I have a horz nav bar at the top of my website that has 7 text links & 6 bullets between the text links. Is there a way to evenly space out the text links & bullets horz across the nav bar. I tired it with the following code, all works well except the bullet spacing is weird and off. Much appreciated for some help on this. Here is the code I have.

Here is a link to my code on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mountart/bdzcv/

```
<style type="text/css">


div#container{
width:1020px;

}
div#container ul {
display:table;
width: 100%;
margin:0px 0px;
padding-left:0px;
-webkit-padding-start:0px; /* reset chrome default */
}
div#container ul li {
display:table-cell;
height:20px;
line-height:20px;
width:14.285%;
font-family: "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:12px;    
padding:0px 0px;
text-align: center;
border-right:none;
}
div#container ul li:last-child {
border-right:none;
}

div#container A:link { COLOR: black; TEXT-DECORATION: none; font-weight: normal }
div#containerA:visited {
COLOR: #666;
TEXT-DECORATION: none;
font-weight: normal
}
div#container A:active {
COLOR: #666;
TEXT-DECORATION: none
}
div#container A:hover {
COLOR: #C00;
TEXT-DECORATION: none;
font-weight: none
}
div#container li.headerbullet
{
float:left;
display:inline-block;
width:auto;
margin-left:5px;
margin-right:0px;
height:20px;
line-height:20px;
}
div#container li.headerbullet img
{
margin-top:10px;
}

</style>


<div class="clear"></div>


<div id="container">
<ul>
<li><a href="<%=BaseURL%>/entertainment">ARTS & ENTERTAINMENT</a></li>
<li class="headerbullet"><img src="http://www.hispanicbusiness.com/_client_common/images/main/2012/footer_bullet.png"/></li>


<li><a href="<%=BaseURL%>/technology">TECHNOLOGY</b></a></li>
<li class="headerbullet"><img src="http://www.hispanicbusiness.com/_client_common/images/main/2012/footer_bullet.png"/></li>


<li><a href="<%=BaseURL%>/auto">AUTO</a></li>
<li class="headerbullet"><img src="http://www.hispanicbusiness.com/_client_common/images/main/2012/footer_bullet.png"/></li>


<li><a href="<%=BaseURL%>/sports">SPORTS</a></li>
<li class="headerbullet"><img src="http://www.hispanicbusiness.com/_client_common/images/main/2012/footer_bullet.png"/></li>


<li><a href="<%=BaseURL%>/news/more-news-briefs.asp">NEWS BRIEFS</a></li>
<li class="headerbullet"><img src="http://www.hispanicbusiness.com/_client_common/images/main/2012/footer_bullet.png"/></li>



<li><a href="<%=BaseURL%>/greentech">GREEN ECONOMY</a></li>
<li class="headerbullet"><img src="http://www.hispanicbusiness.com/_client_common/images/main/2012/footer_bullet.png"/></li>
<li><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.hirediversity.com" target="_blank">CAREER NEWS</a>    </li>
</ul>
</div><hr style="margin-top:4px"/>
```

Comment: Are you trying to do something [**like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/bdzcv/3/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's clean up some of that HTML and CSS :)

We can create the bullets using just the `li` parents for each link. The padding on `#container li` will space out the bullets evenly, however large of a gap you want.

**Updated**

The menu is centred by the combination of `margin: auto;` and a fixed width (in this case - `width: 776px;`.

[image: Screenshot]

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/2bUbp/5/)

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="%3C%=BaseURL%%3E/entertainment">ARTS &amp; ENTERTAINMENT</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="%3C%=BaseURL%%3E/technology">TECHNOLOGY</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="%3C%=BaseURL%%3E/auto">AUTO</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="%3C%=BaseURL%%3E/sports">SPORTS</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="%3C%=BaseURL%%3E/news/more-news-briefs.asp">NEWS BRIEFS</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="%3C%=BaseURL%%3E/greentech">GREEN ECONOMY</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.hirediversity.com" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">CAREER NEWS</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#container ul {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 776px;
    border-bottom: dotted 1px #CCC;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
}
#container li:first-child {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 18px;
}
#container li {
    float: left;
    font-family:"Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    padding: 0 30px 0 2px;
}
#container a:link {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#container a:hover {
    color: #F00;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: This worked misterManSam, but all the links are flush left, could not get it to space correctly using padding

Comment: All the links are flush with the left margin of the page, with approx. 5 pixels space between the links and the bullets. the nav bar elements stop about half way across the page, I was looking for something that would evenly space out the text links & bullets across the whole 1020px width of the page.

Comment: yes, centered like that is exactly what I am looking for! Perfect! How did you get it to dot hat? Can you upload the codes on stack exchange? Thanks so much, Ron

Answer (score 0):

You can justify your list elements by making you `ul` have `text-align: justify`. Then, make an `:after` element that has a `width: 100%` to trick it into thinking there is another line.

See here: (Sorry, I removed some of your CSS to make it easier to read.)

http://jsfiddle.net/ECf2u/

```
div#container{
width:1020px;

}
div#container ul {
width: 100%;
text-align: justify;
-webkit-padding-start:0px; /* reset chrome default */
}
div#container ul:after {
content: "";
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
}
div#container ul li {
font-family: "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:12px;    
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}

div#container A:link { COLOR: black; TEXT-DECORATION: none; font-weight: normal }
div#containerA:visited {
COLOR: #666;
TEXT-DECORATION: none;
font-weight: normal
}
div#container A:active {
COLOR: #666;
TEXT-DECORATION: none
}
div#container A:hover {
COLOR: #C00;
TEXT-DECORATION: none;
font-weight: none
}
```

Comment: Sorry tpalmer75, but this didn't work at all, it just stacked the li elements one on top of the other, appreciate trying thou

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler solution, using CSS3 `flex`.

It fully-justifies the menu items, distributing the space evenly around the bullets.

I couldn't figure out how to do the bullets without the extra empty `<li><\li>` elements.

[Link to CodePen](http://codepen.io/TomRobinson/pen/EgGjdo)

```
.menu { font: 14px "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif; list-style-type: none; padding:3px }
.menu a { color: black; text-decoration: none }
.menu a:visited, .menu a:active { color: #666 }
.menu a:hover { color: #c00 }
.menu { display:flex; justify-content:space-between; border: 1px solid black; border-width: 1px 0 }
.menu li:empty:after { content:"\2022" }

<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="/entertainment">ARTS &amp; ENTERTAINMENT</a></li><li></li>
<li><a href="/technology">TECHNOLOGY</a></li><li></li>
<li><a href="/auto">AUTO</a></li><li></li>
<li><a href="/sports">SPORTS</a></li><li></li>
<li><a href="/news-briefs">NEWS BRIEFS</a></li><li></li>
<li><a href="/greentech">GREEN ECONOMY</a></li><li></li>
<li><a href="/career-news" target="_blank">CAREER NEWS</a></li>
</ul>
```

[image: nav bar with bullets between]